# Using redirect_to and passing extra params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to return redirect_to and pass extra params. Here is what I have in my controller:

```
redirect_to(env['omniauth.origin'], :hello => "hello world")
```

This is redirecting to the URL correctly but hello is not being passed. Ideas?

Comment: Is your target (omiauth) an external url?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is `env['omniauth.origin']` a String? If so, I don't think this can work. You could try adding the parameter as:

```
redirect_to(env['omniauth.origin'] + "?hello=helloworld")
```

or something to that effect.

Answer (score 4):

`redirect_to` eventually calls [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionDispatch/Routing/UrlFor.html#method-i-url_for), and if the argument to `url_for` is a String, it simply returns that String untouched. It ignores any other options.

I'd suggest simply using Rails's `Hash#to_query` method:

```
redirect_to([env['omniauth.origin'], '?', params.to_query].join)
```

Comment: I should note that this will only generate a valid URL if `env['omniauth.origin']` doesn't already contain a query string.

Answer (score 1):

Add a path for it in your routes and pass the helloworld as the parameter

```
redirect_to(route_in_file_path('helloworld'))
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a function to `ApplicationController` class

```
class ApplicationController  < ActionController::Base    
  def update_uri(url, opt={})
    URI(url).tap do |u|
      u.query = [u.query, opt.map{ |k, v| "#{k}=#{URI.encode(v)}" }].
                 compact.join("&")
    end
  end
  helper_method :update_uri # expose the controller method as helper
end
```

Now you can do the following:

```
redirect_to update_uri(env['omniauth.origin'], :hello => "Hello World")
```